# What does this pointing hand symbol mean?

Tags: books-generally, shulchan-aruch, symbols-symbology

I've seen in the [Shulchan Aruch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9725&st=&pgnum=103) the [hand symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/261c/index.htm) ( ☜ ) appearing quite a few times.

What does it do? Does it reference to mforshim on the side?

Comment: The common names for this character in typography are *index*, *manicule*, and *fist*. (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(typography))).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In *Orach Chayim*, it refers to a comment by the [*Yad Efrayim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Zalman_Margolis), in the margin.

[The Business Halacha Institute](http://www.businesshalacha.com/) tells me that in *Choshen Mishpat* it points to a *chidush* [a novel thought or opinion].

Comment: Decided that it' a chidush by who? The publisher?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, good question. I know no more than I wrote, unfortunately.

Comment: It appears quite a bit in Yoreh De'ah as well. Also, I noticed that some new publishers use it a little bit differently than older ones, so this answer may be obsolete (or just incomplete). I think some publishers may have a note at the beginning about how they use it. @Shmuel brin

Comment: There's a Yad Efraim on Yoreh Deah as well

Comment: @SethJ see preceding comment.

Comment: @msh210 Thank you.  I didn't even remember commenting on this (still don't).