# What's that pointer finger in pages of Shulhan 'Aruch?

Tags: jewish-books, shulchan-aruch

Is there a name for the pointer finger that appears in certain places in printed pages of Shulhan 'Aruch? I assume its purpose is to highlight an important point, but is it employed in a consistent manner? If so, under what criteria?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/what-does-this-pointing-hand-symbol-mean

Comment: [You](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/what-does-this-pointing-hand-symbol-mean#comment66381_10078) even made a comment there

Comment: Welcome back SethJ! Good to see you

Comment: It will also appear for example in העמק שאלה

Comment: In Shulchan Aruch it's usually Yad Efraim

Comment: @robev, et al., thank you.  I didn't even remember making the comment there (still don't).